# CRUD operations on JSON file using Python(Flask)

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a JSON file called sample.json

```
{
    "emp_details": [
        {
            "emp_name": "test",
            "job_role": "Full Stack"
        },
        {
            "emp_name": "test1",
            "job_role": "x1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Looking to perform crud operations using Python(Flask).
Please help me with a sample code or reference.

Thank you all.

Comment: JSON is a serialization format, not a database. There's no CRUD, you parse the text, modify the resulting objects and serialize them again

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, can you show how to serialize json data

Comment: see https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

The [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) is pretty good. Specifically look at the [minimal example](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) and [APIs with Json](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#apis-with-json).

Here is a basic example that will return the JSON using Flask.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

data = {
    "emp_details": [
        {
            "emp_name": "test",
            "job_role": "Full Stack"
        },
        {
            "emp_name": "test1",
            "job_role": "x1"
        }
    ]
}


@app.route('/')
def read_json():
    return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```